# Transfer a ssh session between the same physical devices from one network to another

Tags: wireless, networking, server, ssh

My server has 2 IP addresses via two networks. Due to some restrictions,my client will be able to access only one of the network at a time. Hence, I want a way to transfer a live ssh session with all the open applications seamlessly from one network to another. The physical devices (client and the server) are the same. What changes is the network through which it connects. can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. SSH is use tcp protocol for session between end's.
TCP create socket address for communication. Socket address is address witch combines `ip_address+protocol+port`. Example of socket address when you go to some web is   `69.59.197.24:80:tcp`. When you move from one network to another you change socket becouse you change `ip address`, and all tcp connection will be killed. More explination about socket address you can find   [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPSocketsandSocketPairsProcessandConnectionIden.htm). Also you can do some resarch for `tcp/ip` protocol.